# Is there automagic translater between POJOs in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have two POJOs.

```
class ZebraDAO {
  Long id;
  Mane mane;
  Tail tail;
  Stripes stripes;
}

class ZebraDTO {
  Mane mane;
  Tail tail;
  Stripes stripes;
  String description;
}
```

Does Spring framework have automagic feature/annotation/naming-convention in creating a new ZebraDTO from an instance of ZebraDAO, based on similarity of names or properties between the two POJOs? i.e., without my having to write any code transferring properties from one to the other.

Comment: Just as a comment: the DAO/DTO approach is old school and time consuming (2+ classes per each entity). I suggest you avoid that like hell and just use interfaces whenever you need to define data subsets from your DAOs.

Comment: Totally agree, but what could you do when the architecture has the DTO generated by XSD? In fact, in my own designs, I have the DTO and DAO as the same object because I am to mix jax-b and jpa annotations onto the same POJO. However, when you plan to have web services that can be implemented either in Java or PHP .... --> XSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using the good-old [Apache Commons BeanUtils.copyProperties()](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)? Spring also has his own flavor of an static [BeanUtils.copyProperties()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

Not with Spring but [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) does that.